# GTK+ for Apple Silicon

Tags: c, gtk, apple-m1

I'm trying to install GTK for my M1 Macbook but I keep getting the error `#include errors detected. Please update your includePath`.

I have tried installing using `brew` and by using the .sh script from their website but neither methods have worked. I'm wondering, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I managed to get GTK+3 installed using brew in a non-rosetta zsh terminal by first installing brew in /opt. However, I now have another issue which is my GTK+3 app seemingly can't load the GTK+3 libraries that have been installed. Have you managed to get GTK installed via brew?

Comment: @muszeo Yep, I installed it using brew but I can't import the library on anywhere. So I tried to reinstall GTK+3 for Python using pip, **python3 -m pip install -U gtk+3** and an errror **ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'gtk+3'** appeared

Comment: yeah looks like we've got a similar issue then. I have a dotnet app that is complaining that it can't load the libobject2 library. I am assuming that the libraries that brew installs are actually ARM libraries. Next stop is to check to see what the PATH is, as per your error I think, to make sure the GTK+3 libraries are actually on the PATH.

Comment: Ok, so I've managed to get mine to fire-up by putting my dotnet executable app into the /opt/homebrew/lib directory where all of the symlinks to the various GTK+# libraries sit. Even though the /opt/homebrew/lib directory IS on the PATH env variable on my machine, for some reason it looks like this is not being picked up by my app. This might be something that is BigSur related perhaps.

Comment: Also, by copying the contents of the /opt/homebrew/lib into the "MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS" folder, I can also get the application to run. However, it will only do so when the app is manually loaded using a terminal with rosetta enabled, it won't work via a non-rosetta terminal or by double-clicking on the .app file.

Comment: Ok -- I've managed to solve this for me. It may help you! I uninstalled home-brew from /opt, deleted all of the remaining /opt/homebrew folders and reinstalled it again from a ROSETTA terminal. I then installed GTK+3 again using this new homebrew, and this looks to have solved the issue.